# USBからUbuntuが起動できない

Tags: ubuntu

PCはWindowsです。ubuntuの環境が欲しくて、USBにubuntuのisoファイルを入れました。そのあとに、再起動してubuntuをスタートさせようとしたら以下のようにエラーが出ます。
[image: このようにエラーが出ます。]
エラーの詳細は下の２文です。
(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
[figure ex.) 135.392108] usb 3-4: device descriptor ewad/all, error -110

いろいろ試したのですが、だめでした。（BIOSなどをいじったのですがだめでした。）
やりたいことはUbuntuをUSBにいれて持ち運べるようにしたいです。ただし、入っているWindowsは何も壊さないようにしたいです。
USB ドライブ側とソケット側の 2.0/3.0の意味は分かりません。
使っているのはUSBはUSB3.0です。
Ubuntuのバージョンは18.04.2。iso.ファイルはUniversal-USB-installerで入れました。
BIOS画面の、BOOTでUEFIとLEGACYモードを両方試したのですが、だめでした。
ダウンロード先は[ダウンロードのふぁいる](http://cdimage.ubuntulinux.jp/releases/18.10/ubuntu-ja-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso)このUbuntu Japanese Teamのところです。[ダウンロードのホームページ](https://www.ubuntulinux.jp/download/ja-remix)64ビットの18.10です。
md5sumはb36979d580c4a95979cdf19bce609513　です。

Comment: やりたいのは、USB からのブートでしょうか、それとも USB からの OS インストールでしょうか？　また、Ubuntu のバージョン等は何でしょうか。USB にどのようにして iso ファイルを入れましたか？　USB ドライブ側とソケット側の 2.0/3.0 は分かりますでしょうか。また、「いろいろ試した」とは具体的にどのようなことをなさったのでしょうか。このあたりを質問文に追記して頂けませんか？

Comment: USB2.0でやったらできました。

Comment: お手軽にubuntuなどlinux環境を試すなら、WSL使うのも手ですよ。

Comment: @Can さん、お疲れ様でした。自己解決した場合、スタック・オーバーフローでは[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)を推奨しています。よろしければお願いいたします :)

Comment: @豚吐露 過去質問を見る限り、元々はWSL環境を利用されていたみたいです。

Comment: すいません、2.0でUbuntuを起動した後に、USB3.0にインストールしてそのあとにUSB3.0で起動しようとしたらできませんでした。エラーはさっきと同じものです。どうすればいいですか？

Comment: ubuntuのisoファイルをmd5sumをwinMd5SumPortableで調べてみたら、hashが違っていました。その後、何回か同じところからubuntuisoファイルをダウンロードしたのですが、すべてhash値が違っていました。どうすれば、正しいubuntuファイルをダウンロードできますか？

Comment: 他の人が確認できるよう「ダウンロードしたバージョンや種類 (32bit or 64bit、バージョン等)」「何処からダウンロードしたかのURL」「比較した元のハッシュ」などを質問文に追記してください。

Comment: すいません、winmd5sumの使い方を間違っていたみたいです。下に、ホームページに載っているMD５sumを別に入力する必要があったみたいです。比べたら同じでした。
けど、もう一回やったら別の問題が出てきたので、新しく質問を立てるのでそちらで、おねがいします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

お使いの機器では Ubuntu の USB 起動メディア(sdc)が、USB 3.0 のポートを使用して起動すると、起動の途中で I/O エラーが発生しておりシステムが起動できない状態のようです。

```
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 30218839
Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 15108392, async page read
Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 15108393, async page read
Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 15108394, async page read
Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 15108395, async page read
```

Windows で USB 3.0 ポートが問題なく使用できているのであれば、Ubuntu ではドライバが対応していない、別途アップデートを行う必要があるかもしれません。